# How to change the background color of the words that start with the specific character

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I have the following sentences:

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum [[dolor]] sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do [[eiusmod]] tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna [[aliqua]] and name
</div>
```

I want to change the background color of any words that start with `[[` and end with `]]` I tried a lot but could not

Comment: "I tried a lot but could not" - can you please provide your attempt(s) so you can see where you went wrong and why it didn't work.

Comment: @Nick Parsons- I used `endsWith()` and `startsWith()` in javascript but I could not use it correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I used endsWith() and startsWith() in javascript but I could not use
> it correctly

The `.endsWith()` and `.startsWith()` methods will check whether the entire string either starts or ends with the characters you pass it, it won't do much other than that. You would need to somehow first find where the `[[` and `]]` is in your text and then perform the highlighting logic.

A more straightforward way would be to first grab the div and its text using `document.querySelector("div")` and `.textContent` to obtain the string within the div. Once you have the text, you can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on it with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The regular expression will:

- Match any text starting with `[[` using `\[\[`
- Group any characters (zero or more `*`) after the previously matched `[[` that are not `]]` using `([^\]\]]*)`. This group can later be referenced using `$1` in the `.replace()` method
- Match two closing brackets `]]` using `\]\]`

If a part of a string successfully matches the regex (ie: all of the points above), it will be replaced by the string in the second argument, allowing you to replace your matched text with a `<span>` wrapping the group `$1` (the text you want to highlight). You can give the span a class so you can style it with CSS to change its background color:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
div.innerHTML = div.textContent.replace(/\[\[([^\]\]]*)\]\]/g, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Lorem ipsum [[dolor]] sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do [[eiusmod]] tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna [[aliqua]] and name
</div>
```